# Django website sometimes doesn't print anything

Tags: python-3.x, django, beautifulsoup, django-views

I developed a website using Django where the HTML content is scraped data from amazon. The page's function is to scrape the data from amazon when I give a search item. I used Beautiful Soup to scrape data. When I ran the function alone without running the server, the output is fine and there is no issue. But when I used that same function in my server, sometimes I get output which is a table of scraped data. But sometimes I don't get any table in my page. I feel like the issue is from the way of adding Django in my code. As I'm new to Django, please check whether I've entered all the code correctly. The code I used is,

views.py

```
def amzlogic(response):
    USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36"
    LANGUAGE = "en-US,en;q=0.5"
    session = requests.Session()
    session.headers['User-Agent'] = USER_AGENT
    session.headers['Accept-Language'] = LANGUAGE
    session.headers['Content-Language'] = LANGUAGE
    title_list = []
    price_list = []
    image_url_list = []
    
    if response.method == "GET":
        search = response.GET.get("search-item")
        search = search.replace(" ", "+")
        url = f"https://www.amazon.in/s?k={search}&page=1&qid=1636019714&ref=sr_pg_1"

        page = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'lxml')

    for item in soup.select(".s-border-top"):
        title = item.select_one(".a-color-base.a-text-normal").get_text()[:25]
        try:
            price = item.select_one(".a-price-whole").get_text().replace(",", "").replace(".", "")
        except:
            price = "No Price"
        image_url = item.select_one(".s-image")

        title_list.append(title)
        price_list.append(price)
        image_url_list.append(image_url.get('src'))

    return render(response, "main/amazonscrape.html", {"title_list":title_list, "price_list":price_list, "image_list":image_url_list})
```

templates.html

```
{% block content %}
    <form method="GET" action="#"> {%csrf_token%}
        <label for="search-query">Search:</label> <br>
        <input type="text" name = "search-item" placeholder="Enter your search item"> <br>
        <!-- <label for="search-query">Number of pages:</label><br>
        <input type="number" name = "page-limit" placeholder="No. of pages"><br> -->
        <input type="submit" name="search" value="search">
    </form>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        {%for title in title_list%}
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{title}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        {%endfor%}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        {%for price in price_list%}
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{price}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        {%endfor%}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        {%for image in image_list%}
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{image}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        {%endfor%}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
{%endblock%}
```

If the error is from someother file, please mention that in the comment. I would also add that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `response` should be `request`, but beyond that, the code looks OK. (Not perfect – I'd use a single list of dicts for the items – but OK.) (Also, you don't use the Requests `session` that you create for the actual request.)

I'd probably refactor the search into another function, á la

```
import requests

HEADERS = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Content-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
}


def do_amazon_search(search):
    search = search.replace(" ", "+")
    response = requests.get(f"https://www.amazon.in/s?k={search}&page=1&qid=1636019714&ref=sr_pg_1", headers=HEADERS)
    response.raise_for_status()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
    items = []
    for item in soup.select(".s-border-top"):
        title = item.select_one(".a-color-base.a-text-normal").get_text()[:25]
        try:
            price = item.select_one(".a-price-whole").get_text().replace(",", "").replace(".", "")
        except Exception:
            price = "No Price"
        image_url = item.select_one(".s-image")
        items.append({"title": title, "price": price, "image": image_url.get("src")})
    return items


def amzlogic(request):
    search = request.GET.get("search-item")
    items = do_amazon_search(search)
    return render(request, "main/amazonscrape.html", {"items": items})
```

> But when I used that same function in my server, sometimes I get output which is a table of scraped data. But sometimes I don't get any table in my page.

I'd just guess sometimes there aren't any tags in the scrape output that would match `for item in soup.select(".s-border-top"):`, and so you end up with no items.

Comment: Thank you so much @AKX. Then what tag can I use in soup.select() to make it work well?

Comment: If possible can you explain me what is the difference between request and response in the function?

Comment: Django views take in requests and return responses. As to what to use in the soup, I don't know. It's possible that Amazon is just returning an error page or something?